# Is it possible to disable the dropdown behavior of <select> and <option> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically have a bunch of select/option tags that are generated through mysql->php->AJAX.

I would like to write a client side handler that will transform some specified select/option tags from dropdown menus, to side by side boxes ([kinda like this](https://www.nordstromrack.com/shop/product/857962/chinese-laundry-forget-you-platform-sandal?color=Peacock%20Satin#results)), based on what the select/option tag is actually selecting.

Is it possible to disable the dropdown behavior of select/option tags while maintaining their :select like behavior using CSS?

I would like to avoid changing the tag type.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but you can have a look at the examples of [this](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin

Comment: The plugin replaces the select/option tags with divs. I've considered doing this, but I'd rather have a CSS solution.

Comment: You can't do it with CSS alone as you need to know what the user selected and for that you'd need javascript

Comment: The best thing you can do here is use a hidden field. Keep this hidden field as empty, whenever a particular size is chosen i.e A tag is clicked, fill this empty field with a tags value. Same can be done for color option also.

Comment: You can use  jquery's display-block plugin for side-by-side display http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid

Comment: That plug in is awesome. Will use. Thanks.

I should really learn a bit more about jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

`<select name="abc" class="def" id="ijk" disabled="disabled">
    <option> option1 </option>
    <option> option2 </option>
  </select>`

Using javascript you can remove/add "disabled" attribute to enable/disable drop down option.